# MySQL : employee are sorted according to job level and job position conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table of employee. As follows

| name | surname | level | job_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp 1 | sur 1 | 13 | Assistant Governor |
| emp 2 | sur 2 | 12 | CEO |
| emp 3 | sur 3 | 12 | CEO |
| emp 4 | sur 4 | 12 | Special |
| emp 5 | Sur 5 | 11 | Vice CEO |
| emp 6 | Sur 6 | 11 | Director |
| emp 7 | Sur 7 | 11 | academician |
| emp 8 | Sur 8 | 10 | Vice Director |
| emp 9 | Sur 9 | 10 | academician |
| emp 10 | Sur 10 | 10 | academician |
| emp 11 | Sur 11 | 10 | academician |
| emp 12 | Sur 12 | 9 | Assistant Director |
| emp 13 | Sur 13 | 9 | academician |
| emp 14 | Sur 14 | 9 | expert |
| . |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |
| . |  |  |  |
| emp 100 | Sur 100 | 2 | employee |

Because within my organization
They put a lot of emphasis on the level and job title.
I want to sort the list of employees with the condition:

1. Sort from 'level' column first. If higher level will come first And lower levels will come later
2. If they are the same level To analyze whether it is 'management' or 'operated'. Where 'management' came first and 'operated' later.
3. In

   1. Management is :  CEO, VICE CEO, Assistant CEO,Director, Vice Director , Assistant Director
   2. Operated is : Special,academician,Expert,Employee
4. If they are the same level and He is 'managemnt'.I want it to be sorted as follows.

   ```
    1. CEO
    2. VICE CEO
    3. Assistant CEO
    4. Director
    5. Vice Director
    6. Assistant Director
   ```
5. If they are the same level and He is 'operated'. I want it to be sorted as follows.

   ```
    1.  Special           
    2.  academician
    3.  Expert
    4.  Employee
   ```

I should write Mysql to sort the names of the employees. According to the level and position

---

PS. sorry english .

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have assistant governor at level 13 but is neither management nor operated?

Comment: P.Salmon :  Assistant governor is managemment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression in the `order by` clause:

```
order by level desc,
         case job_position
             when "CEO" then 1
             when "VICE CEO" then 2
             when "Assistant CEO" then 3
             when "Director" then 4
             when "Vice Director" then 5
             when "Assistant Director" then 6
             when "Special" then 10
             when "academician" then 11
             when "Expert" then 12
             else 99
         end
```

Make sure the capitalisation is correct (I see a difference in "Expert" and "expert" in your question).

However, it would be better to create a separate reference table (like `job_positions`) where you have all these positions together with a unique `id` (a sequential number) column (to be referenced from your main table), a  `name` (with these values "CEO", ...etc) and an `order` column, which would determine the order. Then you don't need this trickery with a `case` expression, and can just join that table and order by that `order` column.

Comment: I have create reference table (It's job_positions)
I was expecting an answer like that. At that time I was still confused How does 'Rules of the sorting job_position table' to sort names.   And how to ORDER BY in select from table?

But now I can see the way. I will try to follow the advice. hahaha. Sometimes I might overthink until I'm blanking.

Thank you.